# ArcGIS Pro using Tabulate Area tool to summarize individual areas within polygon but areas too large

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, area

I used the Tabulate Area tool to find the areas of each land use type inside the circular polygons but the numbers I am getting make no sense (they sum to be larger than a circle with radius 500m). How can I tell what units the calculated area is in? [image]

Comment: What parameter values are you using with [Tabulate Area](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/tabulate-area.htm)?

Comment: Not sure - how do I find this out?